# ¿Cómo extraer datos de un fichero csv con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Necesito saber como puedo leer y separar datos de un fichero `CSV` que contiene solo valores numéricos en `Javascript`.

Por ejemplo el archivo tiene 3 columnas de números separados por comas y 4 filas, como ser:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

La idea es que pueda almacenar la primer columna en un `array`, la segunda en otro y la tercera en otro, es decir, el resultado final que busco es:

```
array1=[1,1,1,1];
array2=[2,2,2,2];
array3=[3,3,3,3];
```

Desde ya muchas gracias. Aclaro que se trata de un archivo que puede subir el usuario.

Comment: Usar la libreria https://www.papaparse.com/ la uso y no me arrepiento de nada. Nota: No te comendatoria hacerlo a palo, no es anda fácil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución (*básica*) podría ser la siguiente:

- Si el archivo es cargado manualmente, podemos usar un `input type="file"` sobre el cual vamos a detectar el evento `change`
- Para leer el contenido del archivo cargado en el `input`, podemos usar [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

### Ejemplo:

```js
function parseCSV(text) {
  // Obtenemos las lineas del texto
  let lines = text.replace(/\r/g, '').split('\n');
  return lines.map(line => {
    // Por cada linea obtenemos los valores
    let values = line.split(',');
    return values;
  });
}

function reverseMatrix(matrix){
  let output = [];
  // Por cada fila
  matrix.forEach((values, row) => {
    // Vemos los valores y su posicion
    values.forEach((value, col) => {
      // Si la posición aún no fue creada
      if (output[col] === undefined) output[col] = [];
      output[col][row] = value;
    });
  });
  return output;
}

function readFile(evt) {
  let file = evt.target.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    // Cuando el archivo se terminó de cargar
    let lines = parseCSV(e.target.result);
    let output = reverseMatrix(lines);
    console.log(output);
  };
  // Leemos el contenido del archivo seleccionado
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

Comment: Excelente. Muchas gracias ,me aclaraste el panorama notablemente.